# Custom implementation for Auth0 endpoint API?

Tags: auth0, auth0-lock

Is there a way to write my own implementation for an end point API? example, can I write my own implementation for `/dbconnections/change_password` ??

If so, where is that related docs? I searched and found only Auth0 Management API, I've had a look at Rules, but I have no idea if I can use a custom rule to override implementation for script of forgot password?

Any idea?

**Edit**

I need to write my own implementation for an existing end point API, to write my own implementation for

/dbconnections/change_password

You might ask why?

In my case, I have my app already written in RubyOnRails, and it already has the implementation of forgot password, thus, I just need to call my app method at the endpoint API for the forgot password, which is called by Auth0Lock dialog, I then pass the provided user email to my server via restful call in the custom implementation! And that's all what I would need to the integration.

It's super useful feature, I hope I can hear from  Auth0 regarding willingness of adopting such capability, or at least to suggest an idea that is easier for my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good morning Simo, I work with the Auth0 Community. I was able to confirm that this currently isn't possible with a senior engineer. If you feel this feature would bring you value. Please let our product team know at [Auth0.com/feedback](https://Auth0.com/feedback) as ur features are based off of our customers feedback!

Comment: Thanks, how long did it take to get implemented? I need custom implementation as I found that it's easier to call my own forgot password method via restful call to my rails app.

Comment: It's not really possible to give an ETA as it's weigh against competing features. If you've found a work around then I would definitely say leverage that in the mean time.

Comment: I've just posted a feedback, thanks, also kindly see my edit above.